# Error creating strapi project using mongodb

Tags: mongodb, strapi

I installed MongoDB community edition following its [doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/) on ubuntu. Then installed strapi following [its doc](https://strapi.io/getting-started). Started MongoDb in terminal from command-
`mongod` 
Getting the entry

`...
[initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017`

While creating the project with default values using
 `strapi new myStrapiProject` 
throws the error:

[image: strapiProjCreatError]

and mongod log details:

[image: mongodErrLog]

it goes till `connection id: 62` I don't know why. I've tried creating the project by starting MongoDb using its `start, stop` command but no change. I'm completely new to MongoDb and Strapi. Any help would be appreciated. I have referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46999080/mongo-db-sslhandshakefailed) but it didn't solve my issue.

---

Version details:

```
$ mongod --version
db version v3.6.4

$ strapi --version
3.0.0-alpha.12

$ node --version
v9.11.1

$ npm --version
5.6.0

$ git --version
git version 2.7.4
```

Comment: Did you try to run `mongod` in a new terminal window?

Answer (score 0):

check your minimum requirements for the strapi alpha 3.0.0

From the official [site](https://strapi.io/documentation/3.x.x/getting-started/installation.html):

- Node.js >= 10.x
- NPM >= 6.x
- MongoDB >= 3.x